# Program "double reading" a string

Tags: c, string

I need to create a program that reads a string " A = B" and searchs B in an array of variables. If it doesn't find B, then it asks its value and put it in another array.
Well, I don't know if the idea is clear, but here is an example:

```
  while(1){
  printf("Get string\n");
  gets(L);


  if(L[0]=='\0') break;

  if(L[2] == '1') {
          printf("Value of 1: ");
          scanf(" %lf", &m);

          }

          }
  printf("\nbreak");
```

I need that this program stops when we type enter, so I used if(L[0]=='\0') break; for it.

My problem is: Everytime I ask the value of B, my program read a "ghost string" L, it is, it doesn't let me put the value of L and the program stops. It is almost double reading the string, but it breaks because of the condition L[0] != '\0'. What am I doing wrong? 
If we remove this condition, then the program print 2 times "Get string", without asking me to enter the string 2 times..

Comment: Why don't you take a little more time to clarify your comment. It'd help us all.

Comment: Aradom, I'm sorry if it is not clear. I need to do a compiler for arithmetic expressions and if a variable of <expression> is not in the array of variables, when I try to read its value my program read an empty string L too before it asks to enter another string L

Answer (score 2):

Don't (ever) use `gets()`. It's not good.

Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead, noting that it stores the linefeed. Use some higher-level function (like [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)) to parse out the input. Likewise, use another `fgets()` + `sscanf()` combo to do the value reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, since you never check for errors (including end of file). That's why you're reading twice.

Instead do e.g.

```
while ((fgets(L, sizeof(L), stdin) != NULL)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but can you help me a little more? I have no experience with this function, so I think I'm not using it corretly. Should I keep gets? When I keep it, my program have to read the string twice to ask the value of 1. And when I do not keep it, it keep asking the value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You scanf doesn't consume the line terminator, just what is typed before it. So the gets() then sees the line terminator, and returns an empty string.